# Why is my for loop not updating a given variable?

Tags: python, dice

```
import random
stats = [0,0,0,0,0,0] 
def single_roll(n,fixed=(),sides=6):
    for x in range(0,n):
        dice = random.randint(1,6)
            if dice == 1:
                stats[0] += 1
            elif dice == 2:
                stats[1] += 1
            elif dice == 3:
                stats[2] += 1
            elif dice == 4:
                stats[3] += 1
            elif dice == 5:
                stats[4] += 1
            elif dice == 6:
                stats[5] +=1
```

This is my current code, I am trying to create a list of the number of occurrences of numbers 1-6 when rolling n amount of dice. When I run my code it only prints a list with 6 zeroes. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you actually calling your method anywhere?

Comment: Sorry I am very new to Python and don't know what a method is.

Comment: I have updated my answer. single_roll is a function/method. Think of it like a task. So say the function rolls some dice. You need to tell the function to run. So you need to call single_roll(6). (6) can be replaced with how many dice you want to roll.

Comment: Zach, what is the purpose of the line starting with 'def'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`def single_roll(n,fixed=(),sides=6):` is creating a function. This code itself does not run unless you actually call it. Think of it as a task, you need to tell the task to run. An example is below.

```
import random
stats = [0,0,0,0,0,0] 
def single_roll(n,fixed=(),sides=6):
    for x in range(0,n):
        dice = random.randint(1,6)
        if dice == 1:
            stats[0] += 1
        elif dice == 2:
            stats[1] += 1
        elif dice == 3:
            stats[2] += 1
        elif dice == 4:
            stats[3] += 1
        elif dice == 5:
            stats[4] += 1
        elif dice == 6:
            stats[5] +=1
single_roll(6)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're defining the single_roll() function, but never actually calling it. So you're giving yourself the mechanism to roll dice with, but you're never actually rolling.